# Images on Buttons

Tags: iphone, button

I have a app that has multiple buttons that are all assigned images in the interface builder. I then change there images during the application. What i want to know how would you is to change the images back to the original image....I did it by the following code but it keeps crashing the app

```
- (IBAction)resetCards
{
    NSString *cardImage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"CardBackground.png"];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:cardImage];

    [holdCardOne setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [holdCardTwo setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [flopCardOne setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [flopCardTwo setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [flopCardThree setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [turnCard setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [riverCard setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cardImage release];
    [buttonImage release];

}
```

Comment: @user517814 - You should close (mark the best answer as accepted) some of your older questions. Both yourself and the people with the relevant answer will receive reputation points. :-)

Comment: I dont care about reputation points???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `[buttonImage release]` -- it is being autoreleased.

Usually only call release if you call alloc, copy, or retain.  Always check the documentation for a message that returns an object if you are unsure, but normal Objective-C process is to return objects that autorelease.

Comment: I'd also question the use of initWithFormat: instead of just using the constant passed into it?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lou's answer, why not use:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardBackground.png"];
```

Instead of creating an NSString?